# How to force Samsung Galaxy devices to use Chrome webview in hybrid apps

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome, android-webview, samsung-galaxy

A hybrid app that I am currently working on has thrown up an unexpected issue when running on Samsung Galaxy devices - there is a bottom toolbar that hides part of the app screen.  My understanding is that this is a bit of browser chrome coming from the Samsung Internet browser which apparently is used by default on Galaxy devices.

There is a fix of sorts for this as explained [here](https://allthingssmitty.com/2020/05/11/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/). However, what confuses me here is this - my understanding was that starting with Android 6 the WebView used by hybrid apps was automatically based on Chrome which gets updated on Androids at pretty much the same time as desktop Chrome.  This browser chrome issue suggests that is not the case - at least with Samsung Galaxys.

My question - is there a way to "force" Chrome Webview to be used as the underlying browser?  I am working in Flutter and using the [Flutter Webview plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin).

Comment: you say `I am working in Flutter` so, i've added the flutter tag to your question

Comment: You are wrong, starting from android 7 webview use chrome